# Concequence of using APPDATA in application run from USB

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` in my application.

If the application is installed on a USB drive and run from there will it still be able to access this directory?

Will it be a directory on the host machine still, or will it be a directory on the USB drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will always be a directory on the machine.

ApplicationData is a folder where applications installed can use to store data which are **profile-specific**. So in contract to where they are installed (usually Program Files directory) which is not profile specific, this data will be *different for each user logged on* to the machine.